# How do I find latest invoice number & dates?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-arrayformula, vlookup

Trying to find a formula for the latest date and invoice number.

[image]

Here is my sheet:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_rFYDCQhqfrsU9claYPHQTrEz68zpUFKG9HZqqV4Z8/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Sorry, but SE sites are not "Can you do my work for me". And asking for *urgent* and *quickly* from volunteer contributors is not very considerate. Please [edit] your question, describe the problem here, tell us what you've tried and where you are stuck.

Answer (score 0):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA({
 QUERY({Billing!A2:G, TEXT(Billing!F2:F+1, "d-mmm-yyyy")},
 "select Col5,Col8,Col1,Col6,Col7 limit 1 offset "&COUNTA(Billing!A2:A)-1, 0);
 QUERY({'FY 2019'!A2:G, TEXT('FY 2019'!F2:F+1, "d-mmm-yyyy")}, 
 "select Col1,Col8,Col3,Col6,Col7 limit 1 offset "&COUNTA('FY 2019'!A2:A)-1, 0)})
```

[image: 0]

---

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(D2:D&E2:E, 
 {'FY 2019'!F2:F&'FY 2019'!G2:G, 'FY 2019'!C2:C; 
  Billing!F2:F&Billing!G2:G, Billing!A2:A}, 2, 0)))
```

[image: 0]

Comment: Hey, many thanks for your help. But I was trying to build something with UID as there will be 1000 UID's .

Comment: @SharathShetty That is what you get if you don't ask clear questions. You waste people's time.

Comment: @JanDoggen I understand but consider the fact that I am using this platform for the first time, surely give more inputs when I ask something next time. My intention was not to waste someone's time

Comment: to include UID you could do this: `=ARRAYFORMULA(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A&D2:D&E2:E, 
 {'FY 2019'!A2:A&'FY 2019'!F2:F&'FY 2019'!G2:G, 'FY 2019'!C2:C; 
  Billing!E2:E&Billing!F2:F&Billing!G2:G, Billing!A2:A}, 2, 0)))`

Comment: @SharathShetty how about getting it all in one go? answer updated... - https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1T_rFYDCQhqfrsU9claYPHQTrEz68zpUFKG9HZqqV4Z8/edit#gid=649214149&range=A2